# hide grub menu and initial loading message

Tags: debian, boot, grub, plymouth

With Debian 9.9 and GNOME 3.22, I'm trying to load the OS without boot menu. I've installed plymouth to show a graphical loading and set this options in grub:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

But for a split second, I still see some kind of grub menu. This time with no options.

What I see is an image located here
`/usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png`, and a text that says

```
loading linux 4.9.0-9-amd64...
loading initial memory image...
```

Then plymouth theme is shown and normal boot happens.

Is it possible to hide this? I would like to just see the theme

Answer (score 1):

A suggested solution from https://askubuntu.com/questions/248/how-can-i-show-or-hide-boot-messages-when-ubuntu-starts...

> ...for just a (usually) black screen, try:
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=quiet   #Don't show Ubuntu bootup text
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty12" #Don't show kernel text
> ```

Comment: if I remove splash then plymouth is not showing....If I do the tty12 thing, then computer halts when trying to show plymouth

Comment: now I can't boot

Comment: i'ts like plymouth is broken now and can't boot. how can I fix this? I need to edit grub

Comment: What is displayed? Is it just displaying a blank screen?

Comment: after that split second that I was trying to avoid, I see 3 square dots (plymouth) and that's it. It stays there and can't use my pc

Comment: Booting from a live distro and editing /etc/default/grub from there may get around the problem, as suggested at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1650021. (I get that your's is Debian, but Ubuntu info seems to be what's turning up.)

Comment: Didn't expect the bit I cited would cause such problems... Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

`GRUB_TERMINAL=console`, once it is showing this png file!

Answer (score 1):

A solution that finally worked for me under Debian 10.9 (Buster):

```
$ uname -a
Linux hmi 4.19.0-16-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.181-1 (2021-03-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/default/grub
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash gfxpayload=text loglevel=3 rd.systemd.show_status=auto rd.udev.log-priority=3 vt.global_cursor_default=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=ttyS0"

$ sed -i 's/^quiet_boot="0"/quiet_boot="1"/g' /etc/grub.d/10_linux

$ update-grub
$ reboot
```

GRUB should now be silent and there should be no visible boot messages on the screen (note: some variables set in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` are probably not necessary). - [This gist](https://gist.github.com/thewh1teagle/feb6f1ec221e8bad3b1207abff04c4e7) helped to solve the issue.

*This solution is not related to plymouth, but might still add some valuable information to solve the original issue.*

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting these lines in `/etc/grub/grub.cfg`

```
echo    'Loading Linux XXX-generic ...'
echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
```

Worked for me

Comment: Didn't you mean: `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`? On Debian 10.9 that file is generated after invoking `update-grub`, and shouldn't be edited manually. Instead, you can change the `quiet_boot` variable in `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` in order to remove those messages from the resulting config.